# How to create a function that combines 3 plots in one plot using R

Tags: r, function, plot

I want to combine three plots that I made using the following function

```
#FUNCTION
dlogistic<-function(k=300,rd=0.599,NO1=2,t=20){
    N<-c(NO1,numeric(t))
    for(i in 1:t){
        N[i + 1] <- N[i] + rd* N[i] * (1-N[i]/k)
    }
    return(N)
}

#Plot #1
Nts <- dlogistic()
Nts

#Plot #2
K450<-300*1.5
n450=dlogistic(k=K450)
n450

#Plot#3
k05<-300*0.5
n05=dlogistic(k=k05)
n05
```

The first plot is named `Nts`, the second, `n0450`, and the last, `n05`. Also, I want to use the `matplot` command somehow.

Comment: please indent your code so we can read it with ease. and make sure it runs as well. as it stands I have no idea what you are talking about as the code itself also doesn't run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one using base R. First `plot` one of them and then add others using `lines`. Make sure you set the `ylim` to encompass the whole range of data.

```
graphics.off()
windows(width = 6, height = 6)
plot(Nts, type = "l", ylim = c(min(Nts, n450, n05), max(Nts, n450, n05)))
lines(n450, type = "l", col = "red")
lines(n05, type = "l", col = "blue")
legend('topleft', legend = c("Nts", "n450", "n05"), lty = 1, col = c("black", "red", "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With `matplot+matlines`:

```
matplot(1:length(Nts), cbind(Nts, n450, n05), pch=19, xlab='x', ylab='y')
matlines(1:length(Nts), cbind(Nts, n450, n05), xlab='x', ylab='y')
legend('topleft', legend=c('Nts','n450','n05'), col=1:3, pch=19, lwd=1, lty=1:3)
```

[image]

With `matplot` only:

```
matplot(1:length(Nts), cbind(Nts, n450, n05), type='l', xlab='x', ylab='y')
legend('topleft', legend=c('Nts','n450','n05'), col=1:3, lwd=1, lty=1:3)
```

[image]

With `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=1:length(Nts), y=Nts, col='Nts')) +
  geom_line(aes(x=1:length(n450), y=n450, col='n450')) +
  geom_line(aes(x=1:length(n05), y=n05, col='n05')) +
  xlab('x')+
  ylab('y')+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]